# How to cast CharArray to Array<Char> in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What happens is that `"mystring".toCharArray()` returns a `CharArray` but I need an `Array<Char>`.

1. Why `CharArray` exists? what's the idea behind it?
2. How can I cast a `CharArray` to `Array<Char>`?

I found one way to make it `Array<Char>`

`"mystring".toCharArray().map { it }.toTypedArray()`

but is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first part of your question, refer to the "Basic types" section of the [official language documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html):

> Kotlin also has specialized classes to represent arrays of primitive types without boxing overhead: ByteArray, ShortArray, IntArray and so on. These classes have no inheritance relation to the Array class, but they have the same set of methods and properties. Each of them also has a corresponding factory function:

For the second part of your question, it seems you don't need the `map`. You can just do:

```
"mystring".toCharArray().toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is mapping the `CharSequence` to `it` which will give you a `List<Char>` which then can be converted to the desired `Array<Char>`:

```
"mystring".map { it }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: another alternative: `"hello".toList().toTypedArray()`